# How do you change orientation in iOS

Tags: ios

I have made an iOS project but don't know how to lock the orientation. How do i do that?

EDIT: i tried adding it programmatically but didn't work

Comment: EDIT: i tried adding it programmatically but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the project settings and below you have 4 options remove or add checkmarks to change orientations.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your Xcode project in the navigator (should be the very top file) then go to the General tab for your main target, there will be 4 check boxes under the title Device Orientation. Select those based on the orientations that you would like to allow